# Does RedShift copy command supports storage class option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In my Amazon S3, there are two type of objects based on Storage Class. One is **Standard** and another one is **Glacier**. Is there a way to specify storage class option like this with copy command?

```
copy <table_name> from 's3://<bucket_name>/<object_prefix>' storage-class 'standard';
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not.

You can look at `COPY` command's documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html).